# Jquery function call with some events at the divided files

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with calling javascript function with jquery at the divided files.

Here is the codes.

**responsive-input.js**

```
function setDataToTarget(target, data) {
alert($(target));
if (!!$(target)) {
    $(target).val(data);
    }
}

function setInputHandler(target) {
    const element = $(this);
    element.on("input", setDataToTarget(target, element.val()))
}

$.fn.responsiveInput = function(target) {
    $(this).each(setInputHandler(target));
}
```

**base.html**

```
...
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('input[name="price_expected_input[]"]')
            .responsiveInput($('input[name="price_expected[]"]'));
});
```

I has intended that it works as the code does below.

```
$('input[name="price_expected_input[]"]').each(function() {
    $(this).on("input", function() {
        $('input[name="price_expected[]"]').val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

but it doesn't work because of the element in the `setInputHandler` function. I want to know how to make it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this`, inside the setInputHandler function, is referring to the window object.  You could pass the element to that function from the each method, like this:

```
function setInputHandler(e, target) {
    const element = $(e);
    element.on("input", setDataToTarget(target, element.val()));
}

$.fn.responsiveInput = function(target) {
    $(this).each(function(i, e){setInputHandler(e, target)});
}
```